# Why can't I subscribe a method that fits the signature of my delegate from another class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates

I am making an inventory using Brackey's YouTube tutorials.I have an Inventory class and an InventoryUI class.

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

#region Singleton
public static Inventory instance;

private void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("More than one instance found!");
        return;
    }
    instance = this;
}
#endregion

public delegate void OnItemChanged();

public OnItemChanged OnItemChangedCallBack; }
```

and

```
public class InventoryUi : MonoBehaviour {

Inventory inventory;

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    inventory = Inventory.instance;
    inventory.OnItemChangedCallBack += UpdateUI();
}

public void UpdateUI()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < inventory.items.Count)
        {
            slots[i].AddItem(inventory.items[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            slots[i].ClearSlot();
        }
    }
    Debug.Log("Updating inventory ui");
}
```

}

Where I subscribe the UpdateUI method, it says "cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Inventory.OnItemChanged'"

I'm completely lost as to why I can't sub this method. I can subscribe a method in the Inventory class just fine with the same signature.

Comment: You're *calling* a method instead of using method group syntax. Just remove braces: `inventory.OnItemChangedCallBack += UpdateUI;`.

Comment: Wow. What a mug. Fully appreciate that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot and didn't realize I had parentheses on the end of the method I was subscribing, which meant I was trying to subscribe the result of the method call, rather than the method itself.

Thanks Dennis.